# Solving a complex equation by multiplicative inverse. Solution verification

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I have the following simple equation in $\Bbb{C}$

$$(1 − 2i) · x = 2 + i $$

I can solve it by using the multiplicative inverse on the left side

It is defined as

$$\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+x_1^2},\frac{-x_1}{x_0^2+x_1^2} $$

Which is

$$\frac{1}{1^2+(-2i)^2},\frac{2i}{1^2+(-2i)^2} $$

Which is equal to

$$\frac{1}{1+4i^2},\frac{2i}{1+4i^2} $$

$$\frac{1}{1-4},\frac{2i}{1-4} $$

Which would be

$$\frac{1}{1-4},\frac{2i}{1-4} $$

In coordinate form this would equal to

$$\frac{1+2i}{-3}$$

However in the script the multiplicative inverse is

$$\frac{1+2i}{5}$$

Where is the error?

Comment: The error is that $x_1$ is equal to $-2$ not $-2i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of $a+bi$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real and not both $0$) is $\dfrac{a}{a^2+b^2} - i\dfrac{b}{a^2+b^2}$.

The mistake was using $a^2 + (bi)^2$ in the denominator instead of $a^2+b^2$. **That's wrong**.

The reasoning for the correct form is that you can write
$$\dfrac1z = \dfrac1z \cdot\dfrac{\overline{z}}{\overline{z}} = \dfrac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}$$

Here, $z = a+bi$, and $\overline{z} = a-bi$, and $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, so $|z|^2 = a^2+b^2 = z\cdot \overline{z}$.